# R marginaleffects package set number of cores

Tags: r, r-marginaleffects

This seems like a rather easy question, so sorry if I have overlooked an obvious answer.

When  using `avg_slopes()` from the marginaleffects package I noticed that calculations seem to be done in parallel on all available cores. So far I have not found any possibility to change the number of cores used.
Has anyone any solution of how to do this?

Comment: In principle, `marginaleffects` should not parallelize. That said, `marginaleffects` does use `data.table` under the hood for some operations (merges and such), and `data.table` can use multiple threads. You can try calling: `data.table::setDTthreads(2)`

Comment: Thanks for you answer. Based on you answer I tested a bit and it seems that what I have observed, i.e. that all cores are used, is an effect of `predict()` of `glmmTMB`. So I fit a model with `glmmTMB`, for which I calculate the marginal effects. Do you maybe know how to prevent this ? Otherwise I will close this question and start a new one

Comment: See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/parallel.html Also, please note that there may some issues with the computation of standard errors with glmmTMB. You can follow the discussion here: https://github.com/vincentarelbundock/marginaleffects/issues/810

Comment: Thanks! Yes I am aware of the possible issue reading the standard errors.  The vignette you shared regarding parallelisation in `glmmTMB` is only about building the model, where it can be easily controlled but not about `predict()`. I think predict is discussed here : [https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/713](https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/713) but seems not solved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who happens to stumble across this question.
The question was based on using a `glmmTMB` model as input for `avg_slopes()` and the observed behaviour is caused by the `predict()` function of `glmmTMB`.

`predict()` of `glmmTMB` will infer the number of threads for prediction from the `glmmTMB` model, i.e. if for model fitting 24 threads were used, 24 will be used for prediction as well.

This can be changed by updating the model via `update()`, see also here: https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/713.